# Network-shared Bitcoin core blockchain directory

Tags: bitcoind, server, blockchain

What i'm looking to do is having one parent server for blockchain and more than one server for bitcoin core to divide effort on more than one server and save disk storage.

Let's pretend that i've installed Bitcoin core on serverNum1

And i've Bitcoin core installed on four servers on the same network.

if i point `datadir` in `bitcoin.conf` on these four servers to serverNum1 blockchain data directory and set custom location to wallet.dat file for each server, would it work with no problems? does anyone tried it before?